# Spring Boot Actuator 1.4.7 - missing Health Endpoint (404) on my REST app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've included Spring Actuator in my Spring Boot app but the health endpoint is not there/returning a 404. I can GET many of the other actuator endpoints and see them listed in the Tomcat log i.e.

```
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}]
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics//{name:.*}]
    EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace
```

Below are application.properties
        spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8

```
    # ----------------------------------------
    # SECURITY PROPERTIES
    # ----------------------------------------

    # SECURITY (SecurityProperties)
    security.basic.enabled=false

    # ----------------------------------------
    # ACTUATOR PROPERTIES
    # ----------------------------------------

    # ENDPOINTS (AbstractEndpoint subclasses)
    endpoints.sensitive=false
    endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
    endpoints.health.sensitive=false

    # MANAGEMENT HTTP SERVER (ManagementServerProperties)
    management.security.enabled=false
```

Would anyone have any ideas what would stop the Actuator health endpoint being created/available?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable other endpoints by this property :

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health, loggers, logfile, configprops
```

Answer (score 0):

Try config `endpoints.health.enabled=true` in application.properties

Comment: Managed to figure out the issue, one of our internal dependencies is an Aspect using _@RequestMapping_ annotation to trigger a DropWizard timer. For some reason this breaks the health endpoint (and some other Spring ones I think).

I added in our domain to the Aspect filter and all is well.